# Android TextView touch events

Tags: android, events

If on a textview I set `onLongClick` event or a touch listener, it works ok, but if I set both, the `TextView` doesn't react on a long click event.

Do you know hot to set both events? I need to change `TextView`'s background on touch (Action down and action up) and to show a context menu on long click event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure, that your OnTouchListener returns false (`return false;`), which means it does not consume the whole event, and it is delegated further to other listeners, such as OnClick and OnLongClick.